# Null Object being created out of JSON data?

Tags: objective-c, json, serialization

So I am attempting to load JSON data from a file called contacts.json and create an objective-C object with the following code:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"contacts" ofType:@"json"];

// Load the file into an NSData object called JSONData

NSError *error = nil;

NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error];

// Create an Objective-C object from JSON Data
// The _contacts array is defined in the header as
// @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *contactsArray;

_contactsArray = [NSJSONSerialization
                  JSONObjectWithData:JSONData
                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                  error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@", _JSONData);
NSLog(@"%@", _contactsArray);
```

When I run this code, the JSONData is able to be output(albeit unreadable), however the contactsArray output is just (null). Why will it not convert this properly?

Comment: If `_contactsArray` is `nil`, log `error` so you can find out what the problem is.

Comment: The same way you log the other values.

Comment: Alright, when I log error I see:

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unescaped control character around character 373.) UserInfo=0x1092c23a0 {NSDebugDescription=Unescaped control character around character 373.}

Comment: Your JSON data isn't valid. You need to fix your contacts.json file. Look around character 373.

Comment: Will do, thank you @rmaddy you've been a great help today